# Check if checkbox is checked or not in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to check if checkbox is selected/checked in this Angular example?
So when user select/check first check box I want to get **true** and when unselect/uncheck it I want **false**.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection() {
      // how to check if checkbox is selected or not

    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <h1>Get checkbox selection (true/false)</h1>
  <label>
    <input id="one" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">This
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">That
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">Lorem
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">Ipsum
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this question is marked duplicate but chosen answer here works better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(event) {
          // how to check if checkbox is selected or not
          alert(event.target.checked);
        };
      })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>Get checkbox selection (true/false)</h1>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection($event)"> This
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection($event)"> That
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection($event)"> Lorem
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection($event)"> Ipsum
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you use `ng-model` instead.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1">
```

Then in your controller `$scope.checkbox1` will be true or false based on if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
if($scope.checkbox1){
    //Checkbox is checked
} else {
    //Checkbox is not checked
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ng-model

```js
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
       
        
      })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>Get checkbox selection (true/false)</h1>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="m1">   This:   {{m1}} 
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="m2"> That:  {{m2}} 
    </label>
    <br>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` to bind a variable with the checkbox which you can access in your `$scope.toggleSelection` function. Here is the implementation

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection() {
       console.log($scope.firstCheckBox);    
    };
  })

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <h1>Get checkbox selection (true/false)</h1>
  <label>
    <input id="one" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()" ng-model="firstCheckBox">This
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">That
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">Lorem
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection()">Ipsum
  </label>
</div>
```